# Dynamic div height with respect to the window

Tags: css, html

The structure of my html is

```
<body>
<div class="divHead"></div>
<div class="divBody"></div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is give a fixed height to the divHeader, let's say 100px, and let the divBody expand to the end of the page exactly, without scroll bars for the browser.

So, if the user's window is 1000px, the body will be 900px and etc...

If i set the divBody height to 100%, it will take the 100% of the body, which means will create a scroll bar in the page.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Never should their be scrollbars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning: FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4vNN/2/

```
.divHead {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.divBody {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.divBody {
   height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Calc is a great tool in the event that he can guarantee CSS3 support for his audience! It's a shame it took so long for `calc` to get implemented into the CSS spec.

Comment: It's a shame that people don't upgrade their browsers more quickly.

Comment: Should probably include a caniuse link along with this.

Answer (score 0):

@crush is certainly right, but if absolute positioning messes up other page elements you can avoid it by just having the elements displayed as blocks : http://jsfiddle.net/kF5wQ/

```
#header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    display:block;
}

#container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
}
```